# How to display html content in Wordpress Custom Field?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**Introduction:**

I'm using wordpress theme called **ClassiPress** I'm very familiar with custom fields and how to use and display them.

In that theme you have ability to create custom fields and than display them for normal users when they are publishing an advertisement (it's cassified ads theme).

**Problem:**

I want to display custom field in which would be displayed html content in this case table which people would fill up with information and **later i would display that table in their post** .

*( sentence in bold text means that i know how to do that part.)*

*Note: I know that by doing this i even risk to get xss holes.*

**Question:**

Is it possible to display custom field with html content in it? Int his case it would be simple html table.

**What i have tried:**

Well since I'm not sure even hfrom what to start i have tried really cheezy and maybe even funny method i have created custom field as text area and went to mysql found that custom field and tried put content in that field in this case just simple `<b>It Works</b>` code to see if that would display bolded text in that text area. But it didn't work maybe becausein database there wasnt right tab;le for it or i did something wrong.

**Additional Information:**

Please also note that in that theme which has custom fields they are limited that means i can't create things that allowed in other custom fields plugins. Pleas etake a look at picture bellow which custom fields tylpes it supports:

[Please click here in order to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc9qp.png)

I would be very thankfull to person which would provide me any solution it could be alternative way but overal would do the idea that i want which i hope i have explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those form elements allow raw HTML. If you are going to put HTML in an input field or textarea, it will need to be HTML-encoded. For example:

```
<b>It Works</b>
```

would need to be:

```
&lt;b&gt;It Works&lt;/b&gt;
```

There are various ways to do that, but it might be hard to make it user-friendly.